# IO buffering turn off

Tags: common-lisp

Commands which are invoked from LISP are having trouble with buffered IO streams, how to turn it off? I found only flushing functions, which are good for nothing in this situation.

Comment: Could you add more details, please, what commands, how invoked, what kind of trouble ?

Comment: *"...in this situation"*. Which situation?

Comment: Shell command to be precise

Answer (score 3):

## You cannot do that

There is no portable way to turn buffering on and off, and for a very good reason: buffered i/o is orders of magnitude faster.

## You should not try to do that

You might be able to find out how to do it in the implementation you use, but it will be a waste of time - you will soon realize that it was a mistake. Please do yourself a favor and do not retrace my steps - I tried that almost 20 years ago.

## There is a better way

When you are done writing, just [flush the output](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_finish.htm).

You can encapsulate this using classes or macros, so that no additional typing would be involved.

## It is better for many reasons

Please note that the approach I suggest will make your code more readable - it will require you to specify your message boundaries explicitly.
Remember, you write code for others (and yourself 6 months from now!) to read, modify, and debug.

Comment: Thank you, but how to do that when funtion run-command for shell script redirect io from command to lisp io streams, i cant flush them because i dont know when command perform read/writes

Comment: Okay, this is a very specific situation: _usually_ shell commands (e.g., `ls`) and lisp shell pipes are _line_ buffered and this is precisely what you want. If this is not the case, please ask a *separate* question with a reproducible example.

Comment: @Seraph Are you having problem with "input buffering" or "output buffering"? That is, are you getting stuck because something you write to the command isn't sent to it (`finish-output` and friends should help here) or are you getting stuck reading something the spawned command has printed? If it is the latter, it's probably getting buffered by the command, not by the pipe or lisp environment.

Comment: You don't always want buffered I/O.  Sometimes, you want to send data over TCP/IP without delay (e.g. disable Nagle's algorithm).  Sometimes, you want to read data as it becomes immediately available without waiting for a new line.  It depends on the native stream (file, terminal/console, socket, device), its configuration, how the other end sends and receives data, if the Lisp implementation can inspect and/or modify its buffering state), if it does its own buffering and how, etc.  Since the *op* didn't specify a case, any guest is a wild guess, any generalized lesson can sound condescending.

Comment: @acelent: the question was general and thus the answer was necessarily general. unbuffered i/o is a VERY rare case, I am still waiting for OP to ask a specific question.

Comment: @sds: thank you for your support, I found problem (and posted answer). Unfortunately, I don't know why my solution work, so maybe If you have some insight ... ?

Comment: @Seraph: I suggest that you ask a separate question, and SBCL experts will help you.

Comment: Input buffering can actually slow things down when your program needs to response as fast as possible. I personally had trouble reading joystick events in Linux (SBCL) because of it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally found the problem (maybe bug??)

Form looks like this (SBCL API)

```
(run-program "sudo" '("mv" "foo.txt" "/usr/bin")
    :search t
    :output t
    :input t
    :wait t)
```

This works exactly how I wanted, problem was that instead of t in input and output args, I specified `*standard-input*` and `*standard-output*` which caused not proper working of command (if invoked program wanted some input from user like sudo for example).

No idea why, but at least, it works now.